# Como inflar uma classe no Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment

Eu precisava inflar um formulário em uma tab, sempre faço o formulário em xml, mas desta vez fiz via código, alguém sabe como faço para exibir minha classe em vez do xml em uma `FragmentTab`?

Código para inflar um xml em uma `View`:

```
if(this.getTag() == "formulario3"){
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario3, container, false);
}
```

Comment: Amigo, não entendi sua pergunta! Ao invés de de criar o xml, vc criou os elementos programando ele em um Fragment?

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que inflar o `fragment` para seu layout primeiramente, utilizando o `LayoutInflater` para mapear o seu `Fragment`.

Exemplo:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.formulario3, container, false);
    TextView text = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.fragmentExemploTxt);
    mTextNoResult = (TextView) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.text_resultado);
    return fragmentView;
}
```